# A pythonic way to take a dictionary as input and return a sub-dictionary as output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am looking for the most pythonic way to take a dictionary and a key name as input, and return the dictionary without the key (and the associated value) as output.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
def SubDict(inputDict,inputkey):
    return dict([(key,val) for key,val in inputDict.iteritems() if key != inputkey])
```

Test case:

```
print SubDict({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},'b')
```

Gives:

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 3}
```

Are there any better suggestions (cleaner and/or simpler code)?

Thank you.

Comment: `return inputDict.pop(inputkey, 0)` ?

Comment: @aws_apprentice: That would just return `inputDict[inputkey]`, wouldn't it? Plus, it would also change `inputDict`, which is not something that I want to take place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your comprehension might as well be replaced with a [dictionary display](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays):

```
{key:val for key,val in inputDict.iteritems() if key != inputkey}
```

But it might actually be faster to copy and remove, as a lookup is O(1). Because of the filter, Python won't know in advance the size of the dictionary, and the hash table might become costly to grow.

```
def SubDict(inputDict, inputkey):
    subdict = inputDict.copy()
    del subdict[inputkey]
    return subdict
```

This is also fairly readable.

If you want to silently ignore the case when `inputkey` is not found, you can replace the `del` with `subdict.pop(inputkey, None)`. This provides a default value (which we ignore) rather than do a double check.

Answer (score 1):

How about this, an alternative way:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

def filtered_dict(inputdict, inputkey):
    return dict(zip(filter(lambda x: x != inputkey, inputdict), inputdict.values()))

{'a': 1, 'c': 3}


%timeit SubDict(d, 'b')
The slowest run took 10.13 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 306 ns per loop


%timeit filtered_dict(d, 'b')
The slowest run took 7.26 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.02 µs per loop
```

Comment: This does the same as OP's expression an order of magnitude slower (largely due to function calls rather than in-expression evaluation; also, with a best of 3 tiny cases comparison, take all the performance measures with a hefty grain of salt). Many, [including GvR](https://github.com/kennethreitz/python-guide/issues/167#issuecomment-6216800), consider comprehensions more readable as well.

Comment: It also relies on both implicitly iterating over keys and explicitly iterating over values in the same order (which it will be [provided the dictionary isn't altered](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)), making for a hefty blend of inobvious behaviour. And allocates a list for the values in Python 2. Wouldn't filtering on `lambda (k,v): k!=inputkey` make more sense, when we're extracting all pairs anyway?